# While running multiple classes via TestNG xml, it executes only one test from a class that has multiple independent tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Language - Java - Selenium Webdriver 
I am trying to implement extent report for multiple classes. Created one base class with @Before suite, @Aftermethod and @After suite and extending it to other three classes as below

I have 3 different classes A, B, C (A and B has single @Test and C has 5 @Tests)

All individual classes has @Beforemethod, @Aftermethod
Using @dataprovider in each class A, B and C

On running all via testng xml, A and B complete all iterations but for C only first test is executed. but on running the class C individually it runs properly. I think its something to do with @ annotations but nothing is working

Comment: What is the best approach for annotations in case we are extending a base class?, Do I need @Aftertest annotation in class C instead of @Aftermethod? but it runs fine when run individually

Comment: Tried alwaysRun = true in each @Test, but didn't work

Comment: See docs for ExtentTestNGITestListener or ExtentTestNGReportBuilder.  Both will do just that.

Comment: Hey Karthik, I found that it also doesn't work even if we remove extent report code. So in normal flow while running the suite from TestNG xml, it skips the subsequent tests from the class where there are multiple @Tests. I will try to go through the listeners you mentioned

Comment: ITestListener is the best to use in most cases, especially where similar tests are created in a single class.

Comment: I'll definitely try that, and another thing I found is, it works if we are separating classes in different tags in xml, and doesn't work when classes are listed one after the other

Comment: Classes under 1 test indicate just 1 test. You need BeforeClass and AfterClass annotations to make it work correctly.

Comment: Where do you recommend inserting @after-before class ? in base class or actual test class ? and should I replace before-after method with beforeafter class ?I tried but its throwing config failure